# Mauve on Ubuntu 16

Tags: bioinformatics

I installed Mauve with the following:

```
apt-get install mauve-aligner
```

and then I ran it with the following:

```
mauveAligner --output=ery.mauve --output-alignment=ery.alignment ery_multiseq.fasta
```

where ery_multiseq.fasta is the fasta file with the different sequences I want to align; each sequence has a unique name. The file is 13 Mb and the average sequence's length is 1.2 Mb.  The output was:

```
Sequence loaded successfully.
ery_multiseq.fasta 1876490 base pairs.
Sequence loaded successfully.
ery_multiseq.fasta 1876490 base pairs.
Sequence loaded successfully.
ery_multiseq.fasta 1752910 base pairs.
Sequence loaded successfully.
ery_multiseq.fasta 1752910 base pairs.
Sequence loaded successfully.
ery_multiseq.fasta 1787941 base pairs.
Sequence loaded successfully.
ery_multiseq.fasta 1787941 base pairs.
Sequence loaded successfully.
ery_multiseq.fasta 346770 base pairs.
Sequence loaded successfully.
ery_multiseq.fasta 398993 base pairs.
Sequence loaded successfully.
ery_multiseq.fasta 454198 base pairs.
Sequence loaded successfully.
ery_multiseq.fasta 731061 base pairs.
Using 15-mers for initial seeds
Creating sorted mer list
Create time was: 1 seconds.
Creating sorted mer list
Create time was: 1 seconds.
Creating sorted mer list
Create time was: 0 seconds.
Creating sorted mer list
Create time was: 1 seconds.
Creating sorted mer list
Create time was: 1 seconds.
Creating sorted mer list
Create time was: 1 seconds.
Creating sorted mer list
Create time was: 0 seconds.
Creating sorted mer list
Create time was: 1 seconds.
Creating sorted mer list
Create time was: 0 seconds.
Creating sorted mer list
Create time was: 0 seconds.
0%..1%..2%..3%..4%..5%..6%..7%..8%..9%..10%..
11%..12%..13%..14%..15%..16%..17%..18%..19%..20%..
21%..22%..23%..24%..25%..26%..27%..28%..29%..30%..
31%..32%..33%..34%..35%..36%..37%..38%..39%..40%..
41%..42%..43%..44%..45%..46%..47%..48%..49%..50%..
51%..52%..53%..54%..55%..56%..57%..58%..59%..60%..
61%..62%..63%..64%..65%..66%..67%..68%..69%..70%..
71%..72%..73%..74%..75%..76%..77%..78%..79%..80%..
81%..82%..83%..84%..85%..86%..87%..88%..89%..90%..
91%..92%..93%..94%..95%..96%..97%..98%..99%..Starting with 43306 MUMs
Eliminating overlaps yields 43767 MUMs
Multiplicity filter gives 0 MUMs
```

The ery.mauve file contained:

```
FormatVersion   4
SequenceCount   10
Sequence0File   ery_multiseq.fasta
Sequence0Length 1876490
Sequence1File   ery_multiseq.fasta
Sequence1Length 1876490
Sequence2File   ery_multiseq.fasta
Sequence2Length 1752910
Sequence3File   ery_multiseq.fasta
Sequence3Length 1752910
Sequence4File   ery_multiseq.fasta
Sequence4Length 1787941
Sequence5File   ery_multiseq.fasta
Sequence5Length 1787941
Sequence6File   ery_multiseq.fasta
Sequence6Length 346770
Sequence7File   ery_multiseq.fasta
Sequence7Length 398993
Sequence8File   ery_multiseq.fasta
Sequence8Length 454198
Sequence9File   ery_multiseq.fasta
Sequence9Length 731061
IntervalCount   0
```

whereas the ery.alignment was completely empty.

What did I do wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: PS: launching the GUI version I got the error: "the sequences might not have any homologous regions" which silly since the sequences are from variants of the same species

Comment: Is it possible that some sequences are in reverse-complement with respect to the others? If so, could this result in the problem you observe with the GUI version? (I have no idea what mauve is supposed to do. Maybe it handles this automatically and my comment is not relevant.)

Comment: Note that there is now a beta bioinformatics stackexchange site where this question might receive answers: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/